# How can I permanently save my chosen DNS settings for my wireless network adapter on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dns, ipv4

I use a custom DNS but I find myself needing to reconfigure it every time I connect, is there a way to save it permanently?

Comment: I too use my own DNS settings and I don't need to ever reconfigure them. What type of connection are you using? We need more information to help you.

Comment: @AndrejaKo when connecting to a wireless network with DHCP enabled it wipes the DNS to choose using the routers one instead by default, at least that is my theory

Comment: Ah! That's important! I think there's a way to solve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm using right now a non-English version of windows 7, so terminology might be a bit different for you.

Go to network and sharing center. There on the left bar, you should have option named manage network adapters or something similar. It should be second from the top. Click on it. You should now get a screen with all network adapters your computer has listed. Find your wireless adapter and right-click on it. Go to properties. There find TCP/IP v4 and double click on it. It should have grayed out fields and it should say that it's using DHCP. On the lower right, you should have a button which says More options or something similar. Click it. Go to DNS tab and you'll see two lists. On the top list click add button and enter addresses of DNS servers you want to use. I think that it should keep settings saved even if DHCP is in use.

Comment: I think you got it, makes total sense. Just applied as such. I'll report back otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to reconfigure it, try this:

1. Press WIN + R
2. Copy in `explorer.exe ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}` (this may look scary, but this is really just the ClassID to open Network Connections)
3. Right click on the connection you want to modify and select `Properties`
4. Now select `IPv4` and click `Properties`
5. Select `Use the following DNS server addresses`, and input your custom DNS info
6. Now select `OK`, and `OK` again on the second window.

Comment: 1) the scary string just opened My Documents, 2) I have already done exactly this and every time I reboot or connect to another network the settings do not save.

Comment: If they reset even when you do that manually, you are likely being limited by group policy or something like Deep Freeze ( http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/DeepFreeze/ ).

Comment: nah, I built this box from scratch with an MS OEM Win7x64 disc, nothing like that is going on here..

Answer (score 0):

Though it doesn't exactly answer your question, I had a similar problem with my MacBook laptop; it wouldn't let me reset my DNS server.  I ended up setting it in my Wireless Router.  If you're good with setting it for everytime you use your router, you can choose this method.